# Confused about Dirichlet L-functions and their poles.

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

I read :  if χ is principal, then the corresponding Dirichlet L-function has a simple pole at $s = 1$.

Probably I need to know what principal is and that will solve my question.

My confusion was this.

Let $\zeta_R(s)$ be the Riemann zeta function with a simple pole at $1$.

Let $\zeta_1(s)$ be the Dirichlet L-function defined as the analytic continuation of

$$ \prod_{p_1} (1+\frac{1}{p_1^s - 1}) $$

where $p_1$ are the primes $ 1$  mod  $4$.

Let $\zeta_2(s)$ be the Dirichlet L-function defined as the analytic continuation of

$$ \prod_{p_2} (1+\frac{1}{p_2^s - 1}) $$

where $p_1$ are the primes $ 3$ mod $4$.

Now we have $\zeta_R(s) = (1+\frac{1}{2^s-1}) \zeta_1(s) \zeta_2(s) $

But $\zeta_R(s)$ has a simple pole at $1$ thus if $\zeta_1(s)$ and $\zeta_2(s)$
both have a pole at $1$ then we have a paradox ;  because the product of 2 functions with a simple pole at $s=1$ equals a function with a pole of order $2$ at $s=1$.

So what is going on here ?

Did I misunderstood ?

Which one ( $\zeta_1$ or $\zeta_2$ ) is missing a pole at $1$ ?

And where is the location of the pole for the one that has no pole at $1$ ?

Comment: The principal character (sometimes denoted by $\chi_0$ or $\varepsilon$) modulo $ n$ is the character defined by $\chi_0(k)=\begin{cases}  1& (k,n)=1\\0&(k,n)>1\end{cases}$. Thus $$L(\chi_0,s)=\sum_{(k,n)=1}\frac{1}{k^s}$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff plz explain further tnx !

Comment: You cannot expect to understand something if you don't read about it first, so I recommend you simply pick a book on Dirichlet characters and have some fun. I am in no position to lecture about them. =)

Comment: I dont have access to books @PedroTamaroff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't quite the Dirichlet $L$-functions you intended, is part of the problem. In general, 
$$ L(s,\chi)\;=\;\sum_n {\chi(n)\over n^s} \;=\; \prod_p {1\over 1 - {\chi(p)\over p^s}}$$
In fact, it appears that the two Dirichlet series you wrote do blow up as $s\to 1^+$ (by a quantitative form of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions). In fact, they cannot have meromorphic continuations, since, as you observe, the combination of their alleged poles at $s=1$ would have to give the simple pole of $\zeta(s)$, which is impossible.

Comment: SO both $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are not meromorphic ?
they both have a single unique singularity at $s=1$ that acts like $\sqrt \frac{1}{z-1}$ ?? But they still have their zero's on the critical line ?
Does this imply the counting function of primes 1 mod 4 (or 3 mod 4) cannot be computed in the same way as done in PNT with the riemann zeta ?

Comment: Your $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are not quite the Dirichlet $L$-functions for which a Riemann Hypothesis is believed to hold. Dirichlet's theorem about primes $p=1\mod 4$ or $3\mod 4$ uses the sum and difference of the logarithmic derivatives of the $L(s,\chi)$'s as I described, instead.

Answer (score 0):

The principal character is the trivial character, the character that takes on the value 1 at every argument.

I think in your example, you are looking at the two Dirichlet characters on the integers modulo 4. One of these has $\chi(a)=1$ for $a$ odd, the other has $\chi(1)=1$, $\chi(3)=-1$ (both characters have $\chi(a)=0$ for $a$ even). The first one is the principal character.

Comment: ?? I thought the first was $\chi(1*)=1$ , $\chi(3*) = 0$ and the second $\chi(1*)=0$ , $\chi(3*)=1$ ?? Where * means prime mod 4.

Comment: Characters are homomorphisms. If $\chi(3)=0$, then $\chi(1)=\chi(9)=(\chi(3))^2=0$. And of course if $\chi(1)=0$ then $\chi(a)=\chi(1)\chi(a)=0$ for all $a$. So whatever you may mean when you write $\chi$, it's not a character. Then see the answer by @paul for the correct definition of the Dirichlet $L$-function.

Comment: Seems like what I wrote is not a Dirichlet L function then ?

Comment: I think @paul has told you what a Dirichlet $L$-function is. If what you've got is different, then it's not a Dirichlet $L$-function. But, you know, the definition is not a state secret; there are plenty of places where you can find out exactly what a Dirichlet $L$-function is. Is there a source that says it is what you say it is?

Comment: I understand now. thanks to all.